# how can i remove strings in a file ?

Tags: php, string, character

this is my code

```
foreach(glob("useri/*.txt") as $filename) {
 echo "<li><a href=$filename>$filename</a></li>" ;
}
```

the output is :

```
useri/caca.txt
useri/pipi.txt
useri/pufu.txt
useri/sadzxc.txt
useri/zan.txt
```

I want to remove **useri/**

TY 
on every submit button a .txt is created.

Comment: Even just `substr` would do the job here...

Comment: CTRL + H and notepad++.

Comment: What if you decide to later restructure your entire folder system? *ah!* You need to pull from the start, right up to the `/`

Comment: i tried with substr, and i get this
useri/caca.txt

caca.txt
useri/pipi.txt
pipi.txt
useri/pufu.txt
pufu.txt
useri/sadzxc.txt
sadzxc.txt
useri/zan.txt
zan.txt

Comment: @user3503874 did you used the code on the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove first 6 characters of your string with `substr`.

Try this :

```
foreach (glob("useri/*.txt") as $filename) {
$file = substr($filename, 6);
 echo "<li><a href=$filename>$file</a></li>" ;
}
```

Comment: ok let me see :),It works , thanks a lot Pars , this was so simple and i was trying for a day.

Comment: @user3503874 your welcome ;) You can mark question as solved .

Comment: mind if i ask , how to mark it ? im new here sry

Comment: @user3503874 there is a check mark at the left of the answers here and you can click on it to mark the question as solved.

Comment: pfff im rly a noob,and again Thank You.